# Log input into array, print only new input

Tags: javascript

Okay I have a a couple of functions. I don't think most of them are relevant. What I want to do is create an html list when you click a button, and store the value in an array. However I want to be able to update this list without outputting the entire array again. I have it set up to accept the input and I can get it to loop and print the array but it will print the entire array and I only want one. This seems like a common thing but my Google-fu returned nothing.

So I have a list variable that connects to an input, logs it into an array, and another function to clear it and print out the values.

Code snippet:

```
var listItemInput= document.getElementByID("listItem");
var listItem= [];

function insertListItem(){
listItem.push(listItemInput.value);
clearAndShow();
}

function clearAndShow(){
listItemInput.value= "";
}
function printList{
   for (var i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++){
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += '<li>' + listItem[i] + '</li>';
}
```

When the printList funciton is called by pressing the button it prints the entire array over however I would like a button that simply prints the newest item. How could I do that?

For clarification, I need to print out the list to html and store the values in an array, the values will later be referenced in an if else argument to combine and print them with new variables.

EDIT:
I plugged in the var = lastIndex and changed it as well as made two more variables for my list. This seems to make it work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep track of the last index printed.

```
var listItemInput= document.getElementByID("listItem");
var listItem = [];
var lastIndex = 0; //Keep track of the last index shown.

function insertListItem() {
    listItem.push(listItemInput.value);
    clearAndShow();
}

function clearAndShow() {
    listItemInput.value = "";
}

function printList() {
    for (; lastIndex < listItem.length; lastIndex++) {
       document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += '<li>' + listItem[lastIndex] + '</li>';
    }
}
```

This approach assumes you won't be removing items from `listItem` array, which you didn't express is something that would be done.

Comment: I might need the option to remove variables.

Comment: For clarification, I need to print out the list to html and store the values in an array, the values will later be referenced in an if else argument to combine and print them with new variables.

Comment: In the end there will also be three different lists to be plugged into a decent size if else argument that reads the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one element, why do you need to iterate?

```
function printList() {
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<li>' + listItem[listItem.length-1] + '</li>';
}
```

Comment: He wants to print all items that have been added since the last time he executed `printList()` I believe.

Comment: For clarification, I need to print out the list to html and store the values in an array, the values will later be referenced in an if else argument to combine and print them with new variables.